# Alternative text for Beamer Berlin navigation menu

Tags: beamer, presentations, navigation

I have an issue where the titles of each section are too long to fit in the navigation menu. However, I do not want to change the title of each section in the table of contents. Is there a way to make the text smaller or to insert a completely different text in the navigation menu?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 \section[short]{Extra ordinary long title which should be shortened}
```